# Proving that a function f(n) belongs to a Big-Theta(g(n))

Tags: asymptotic-complexity, inequality, big-o

Its a exercise that ask to indicate the class Big-Theta(g(n)) the functions belongs to and to prove the assertion.

In this case f(n) = (n^2+1)^10

By definition f(n) E Big-Theta(g(n)) <=> c1*g(n) < f(n) < c2*g(n), where c1 and c2 are two constants.

I know that for this specific f(n) the Big-Theta is g(n^20) but I don't know who to prove it properly. I guess I need to manipulate this inequality but I don't know how

Comment: Is it a homework? (if yes, tag it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function f(x) is Θ(g(x)), iff:

- f(x) is O(g(x)), and
- g(x) is O(f(x))

So, while you could try to prove it in a single inequality, I suggest you break it down into those two parts; first prove that for some n>n<sub>0</sub> f(n) < c<sub>1</sub> g(n), and  then prove that for some N > N<sub>0</sub> g(N) < c<sub>2</sub> f(N). Once you have proven both parts, separately, you can go back to the definition of Θ to prove that f = Θ(g).

Comment: Do you mean 
    *  f(x) is O(g(x)), and
    * g(x) is Big-Omega(f(x)) 
?

Still I can't find a way to work if f(n) to determine n0 and c1 or c2

Comment: @PLS, no I mean that f is big-oh g and g is big-oh f. You don't need to find specific values of n0 or N0... this is simply a formality that allows you to consider only the dominating terms. You also don't need to find specific values for c1 and c2, you just need to show that the highest-order term for both has the same form (so that you could easily choose a c1 or c2 to make it how you want).

Comment: HINT: if you take (n^2+1)^10, the leading order term will be n^20.

Comment: I know that, thanks for helping.
My problem is how to manipulate this concepts to prove my assertion.

Comment: HINT: (n^2+1)^10 = n^20 + k n^18 + ... Find out the value of k, and then compute the value of n=n0 such that kn^18 = n^20 ... For all values of n greater than n0, you know that (n^2+1)^10 < 2n^20 (because the first order term is n^20, and the second order term < n^20).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really an expert at this, but couldn't you prove that f(n) E Ο(n) and that f(n) E Ω(n) and then argue that f(n) E Θ(n) due to the definition of intersection?